# reinterpret_cast adding const

Tags: c++, b-tree, reinterpret-cast

Is it possible to add a const qualifier to only one member of a struct with `reinterpret_cast`.

```cpp
#include <utility>

std::pair<int, int> test;
std::pair<const int, int>& ctest = reinterpret_cast<std::pair<const int, int>&>(test);
ctest.second = 5;
int first = ctest.first;
```

I only want to add const, I don't care about removing it. Google does this in their implementation of BTree. I'm also implementing a BTree so I wonder if this is even legal.

Comment: It's best to recreate the pair and rely on `move` operations instead of luck!

Answer (score 4):

Your code has *undefined behavior* due to violation of [type aliasing rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).